# Please explain the $ use in jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Hi I have this piece of code

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $("#txttstImmLen").blur(function () {
      var myVal2 = $("#txttstImmLen").val();
      $hidden2 = $("#<%=dataImmLenTb.ClientID %>")
      $hidden2.val(myVal2)
  });

});
```

is $hidden2 only accessible inside the blur function? or it can be also accessed outside.

Comment: The question title and content don't match. Decide what do you want to know.

Comment: Please read twice about what you post.
Totally different content.

Comment: The $ in this case has no effect on the variable, its just part of the name

Comment: I already got the answer to my question. It is not globally as everyone said. I have to reinitialize it to use it globally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all..`$`  got nothing to do with this question at all.. `$` here is just a name given to a variable. neither does it makes a variable global nor local.. but the `var` infront of decalring a variable does...

and for the question you asked..yes!!! it can be accessed outside..since you are creating a global variable here.

in your given code... only `myVal2` can be accessed inside blur function .

```
  var $hidden2=...
//^^^--here
```

here add var in front ..this make the variable local.. andcan  only be accessed inside blur function ..

without the var its global variable and hence can be accessed throughout your codes

Answer (score 1):

`$hidden2` is a global variable as there is no `var` in front of it.

Answer (score 0):

if there is no var in front variable that means it is global and you can use it throughout your code .

`$hidden2` is a global variable.

as you have not used var in front of it.